# Type hints syntax error on python 3.5

Tags: python, type-hinting

I've got a code base that I recently sprinkled liberally with type hints. It is python 3.5+ exclusively and the python 3.5 changelog claims type hinting is supported. Unfortunately all the hints raise syntax errors, likewise with simple hints in the interpreter:

```
$ python3
Python 3.5.2 (default, Nov 23 2017, 16:37:01) 
>>> a: int = 5
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a: int = 5
     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any ideas?

Comment: You need a later version for type hints on values and attributes, rather than parameters: https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#pep-526-syntax-for-variable-annotations.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That's an example of a variable annotation, which wasn't introduced until Python 3.6. A variable annotation, defined by [PEP-526](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/), is distinct from a function annotation. Type hints are just one possible use for either type of annotation.