# jupyter notebook not running

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook

when i put in terminal py -m jupyter notebook i got this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\users\dos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 193, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", mod_spec)
  File "c:\users\dos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\runpy.py", line 85, in _run_code
    exec(code, run_globals)
  File "C:\Users\DOs\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python35-32\Scripts\jupyter-notebook.EXE\__main__.py", line 5, in <module>
  File "c:\users\dos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\notebook\notebookapp.py", line 81, in <module>
    from .services.kernels.kernelmanager import MappingKernelManager, AsyncMappingKernelManager
  File "c:\users\dos\appdata\local\programs\python\python35-32\lib\site-packages\notebook\services\kernels\kernelmanager.py", line 18, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.session import Session
  File "C:\Users\DOs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\jupyter_client\__init__.py", line 6, in <module>
    from .asynchronous import AsyncKernelClient  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\DOs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\jupyter_client\asynchronous\__init__.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .client import AsyncKernelClient  # noqa
  File "C:\Users\DOs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\jupyter_client\asynchronous\client.py", line 6, in <module>
    from jupyter_client.channels import HBChannel
  File "C:\Users\DOs\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python35\site-packages\jupyter_client\channels.py", line 46
    time_to_dead: float = 1.0
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

what is the reason for this error?

Comment: @mkrieger1: Are you sure, this issue is related to typed `NamedTuples`? I had a look at the [source code](https://github.com/jupyter/jupyter_client/blob/master/jupyter_client/channels.py#L47) and it seems to be a 'normal' type annotation which are supported since Python 3.5 (exactly the version the OP seems to be using). The class the error arises is derived from `Thread` where I am not sure if this deals with `NamedTuples` under the hood, but I assume that this is rather unlikely...

Comment: no sir i have a problem i cannot launch jupyter notebook and this error appear to me in terminal

Comment: No, I didn't choose this because of namedtuples but because of type annotations. Maybe this would have been better: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51789120/type-hints-syntax-error-on-python-3-5

Comment: Maybe you can try upgrading anaconda or consider reinstalling anaconda

Comment: Did it work fine for the first time? Or is this the first time you are opening jupyter?

Comment: this is the first time sir

Comment: I would suggest you to upgrade python. Which python version do you have currently?

Comment: 3.5.4 . i think so as well

Comment: Yes! here's the matter. You must be using python of a version higher than or equal to 3.6 to support this new syntax.

Comment: Another way would it be to decrease jupyter-client version to 6.1.12 ;). You can do that with "pip3 install --upgrade jupyter-client==6.1.12"

Comment: @rpanai Yeah I would ... but saddly the question is already closed so that was the next best thing that I could think of.

Comment: @Bertoncelj1 the question is open again. Please add your answer.

Answer (score 7):

Another way would it be to decrease jupyter-client version to 6.1.12

You can do that with

```
pip3 install --upgrade jupyter-client==6.1.12
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you have a lower version of python (i.e. 3.5.4), you must consider upgrading your python version equal to or higher than 3.6. This will solve your problem as the syntax is valid in this higher version and no more error will arise.